# how to add "abstract" in Table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, abstract

I form `abstract.tex` as

```
\renewcommand{\abstractname}{Abstract}
\begin{abstract}
... % eng version
\end{abstract}

\renewcommand{\abstractname}{Kurzfassung}
\begin{abstract}
... % de version
\end{abstract}
```

How to add `Abstract` and `Kurzfassung` ( both) in the table of the contents?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! What are you missing?

Comment: @Bernard   I need to add content in the table of content.

Comment: Oh! When you' reading the table of contents, you need to know where it is? :-)

Answer (score 1):

Something along the lines:

```
\renewcommand{\abstractname}{...}
\begin{abstract}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\abstractname}
... 
\end{abstract}

% and similarly for your second abstract.
```

As you have not provided an MWE I guessed that you might want the abstracts' ToC entries to be like a chapter. If they are more like a section then change the `chapter` to `section`. There is more information in the `tocloft` package manual but I don't think that you need the package for what you want.